# How to watch based upon value equality and reference equality?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

The [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) function in AngularJS accepts an optional third parameter.

If it is `false` (the default value), the watch will trigger whenever the watched reference changes. If it is `true`, the watch will trigger whenever the watched object changes according to [`angular.equals`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) (which basically means that the values stored in the watched object have to have changed).

Now, I am looking for a way to have a watch fire its function if the watched reference *or* its content have changed. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

To provide an example of the difficulties I am seeing:

Let's assume I've got an array of objects whose content is editable:

```
var allItems = [{id: 1, a: []}, {id: 2, a: [2, 3, 5]}, {id: 3, a: [4, 6]}, {id: 4, a: []}];
```

A field on my editor's scope receives a reference to the value of the `a` property. For instance, if item 1 is selected, the following has somehow occurred:

```
$scope.currentItem = [];
```

Furthermore, I have registered a watch on that field that checks value equality:

```
$scope.$watch('currentItem', watchFunc, true);
```

Now, I have to distinguish two cases:

- The user uses the editor UI to extend `[]` in the selected item to `[4, 6]`.
- The user selects item 3.

From within `watchFunc`, both of these changes appear to be the same at first glance. To distinguish whether a new item was selected, I need to somehow retain the previous ID, and if it was different from the current one, I need to ignore the change (because nothing was edited in the data, just the selected item was switched). I then need to use `watchFunc` to set the current item ID as the previous ID for the next call.

But then, this is problematic in the following situation:

1. Item 1 is selected.
2. User selects item 4.
3. User adds something in item 4.

The problem here is that the second action will *not* trigger the watch based on `angular.equals`. As a result, the selected item ID will not be updated when the selection changes. Instead, the different item ID will be noticed in step 3, which results in the actual editing action getting ignored.

---

*Obviously, this example is very much simplified; in reality, my object graph consists of nested arrays of objects with various relevant properties each.*

Comment: Register 2 listeners with and without 3rd parameter? :)

Comment: Other than making a custom method I can't recall any easier solution. Never needed to do such but still.. that's a very interesting question.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash: The issue is that I need to suppress my reaction to the value change if the reference has changed. If I just register two listeners, I think I cannot rely on the order they will fire in. Furthermore, the reference change may or may not be followed by a value change, depending on whether or not the two referenced objects happen to have the same content.

Comment: Sounds like bad design. Why would object change and value stay the same? Seems like you should be extending an existing object instead

Comment: @charlietfl: Because the watched objects belong to two different items. When the item selection changes, obviously the reference to the watched object must change, even though their value (e.g. being initially empty) may be the same. Why would that be bad design?

Comment: It's likely bad because you're able to skip `angular.equals` check (immutable value) and you're not doing this.

Comment: @estus: Sorry, I didn't get that. What value is immutable?

Comment: @charlietfl : that may be bad design. However, in general, it sounds reasonable to be aware that an element **somehow** changed, right? Regardless a value or the entire reference changed.. Like.. well. Like angular 2 does?

Comment: A value should change its reference when it partially changes, this eliminates the need to perform deep comparison.

Comment: @estus: How do I notice that it has changed partially unless I perform a deep comparison? You're saying that rather than using Angular bindings to properties in my object graph from e.g. text boxes, I should register change handler functions for each text box and clone the entire object graph every time someone types a letter?

Comment: You shoudn't notice. The piece of code that is responsible for changing this object should take care of this. Yes, more or less. This is how React works in general.

Comment: @estus: Sorry, I don't understand. The piece of code responsible for changing the object is an ordinary [`ngModel` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). How can it possibly know how to indicate the root of our custom object graph in such a way that our custom data handling logic recognizes the object graph as changed in order to push that changed object graph to our DB backend?

Comment: It depends on how the whole thing is organized. If ngModel is responsible for a change, a change should be detected there and not at the root of object graph. That's why there's a problem with design. Regarding the original question, there should be 2 watches. And this smells bad, because deep watch will likely introduce performance hit.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : I guess an ngModelChange is what you may try. Otherwise it's a double watch..

Comment: @estus: "a change should be detected there and not at the root of object graph" - so, you'd rather suggest a separate watch for each changeable value in the object graph? And the handler functions in these watches will then mark the root as modified? I think the practical problem with that is that the UI is dynamically generated and doesn't know the root of the object graph. It's modular and context-agnostic (which, personally, I'd consider very good design (it wasn't written by me, I'm just extending it ...)). As for the performance hit, it's not noticeable in other places where we use ...

Comment: ... such watches, but I'll watch out (no pun intended) for it.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Yes, I expect it to be potential performance killer (surely depends on the size of the object). If you're using Angular 2+, I'd suggest to check how reactive forms work for some inspiration, they do good job propagating changes in separate fields (form controls) up the root (form group) by using RxJS BehaviourSubject for controls internally.

Comment: @estus: Unfortunately, we're using AngularJS 1.5 and the codebase is way too large to migrate to 2+ at this point (at least within the time and workforce restrictions in place). Also, the root of the object graph is not the root of the UI hierarchy (the UI hierarchy in question only represents a part of the object graph, the rest being in something like other tabs). Still, thank you for the suggestions; I will check out how RxJS BehaviourSubject works.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper could you please provide us an example which doesn't work as you would have expected?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think you should not rely on the order and simply call your function once upon the last change (you can use `$timeout` to debounce multiple calls). Probably something like this could work for you, please take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/v6jov39j/1/

Comment: @krutkowski86: I have added a minimal exemplary description of the issues I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qybc07zs/

Hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Testing scenario:

```
1. Select 1
2. Input 4 => Add
3. Input 6 => Add
4. Select 3
5. $watch occurs
```

**AngularJS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.allItems = [{id: 1, a: []}, {id: 2, a: [2, 3, 5]}, {id: 3, a: [4, 6]}, {id: 4, a: []}];
    $scope.currentItemObject = {};
    $scope.currentItem = [];

    $scope.updateCurrentItem = function(item){
        $scope.currentItem = angular.copy(item.a);
    };

    $scope.addItem = function(){
      if($scope.newItem !== undefined){
        $scope.currentItem.push($scope.newItem);
        $scope.newItem = undefined;
      }
    };

    $scope.$watch(function(){ 
      return {id: $scope.currentItemObject.id, a: $scope.currentItem};
    },function(newValue, oldValue){
      if(newValue !== oldValue){
        console.log('$watch', $scope.currentItem);
        $scope.lastUpdate = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      }
    },true);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label>Items: 
    <select ng-options="item as item.id for item in allItems" 
      ng-model="currentItemObject"
      ng-change="updateCurrentItem(currentItemObject)">
      <option style="display:none" value="">-- select item --</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <div>
    <label>New item
      <input type="number" ng-model="newItem">
    </label>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addItem()">
      Add
    </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    Current item: {{currentItem}}  
  </div>
  <br/>
  <pre>
    Last update: {{lastUpdate}}
  </pre>
</div>
```